# xcode tabbar application - device rotation issues

Tags: xcode, orientation, device, tabbar

I am writing a simple tab bar app that is set to autorotate. I need to re-draw some object on the screen depending on the device orientation. for that have notification turned on and attempt to get the current width of the screen. everything is working but I get the portrait width when in landscape mode and vice versa!@?

`AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Interface `viewWillAppear:`

```
NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
           name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
         object:nil];
```

Interface `orientationChanged:`

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    NSLog(@"Portrait Width: %f", self.view.frame.size.width);
}
else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    NSLog(@"Landscape Width: %f", self.view.frame.size.width);
}
```

On an iPad I get:
Portrait Width: 1024
Landscape Width: 768

Why don't I get
Landscape Width:1024 and Portrait Width: 768

This only happens on application start. Once I click on another tabitem the reporting is correct.

I should add the I had this app written with stroyboard before no problems there, but because of the IOS limitations (deployment target) I rewrote it to include 4.0. That is where this problem started.

Searched up and down for a solution but can not figure it out.
Any ideas what is going on here?